# Populating Vue.js Select Box with Nested JSON Array

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to implement a select box in Vue.js in which its values are populated with a data member within an array, WITHIN a JSON object.

Select Box:

```
  <v-select
      :items="JSONResponse"
      v-model="selectedMember"
      label="Select A Team Member"
    ></v-select>
```

The JSON response looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_team": [
                {
                    "_id": "1",
                    "username": "member_1"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "2",
                    "username": "member_2"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "2222",
            "name": "team_test"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the select box to display the usernames of the team members(_team.username). I've attempted to write a for loop to iterate over the JSON objects, however I'm running into problems when trying to dive into the nested array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should do the trick:

```
<v-select
  :items="JSONResponse.data[0]._team.map(member => member.username)"
  v-model="selectedMember"
  label="Select A Team Member" />
```

Comment: Hey, I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error when trying your solution, do you know why this is?

Comment: Ah I didn't realize `JSONResponse.data` was an array. I've just updated my answer accordingly